# Excel 2010 - Filter Worksheet Based Upon Values In a Column In Another Worksheet

Tags: excel, filtering

**Worksheet 1 ("WS1")** has many rows and 26 columns.

**Worksheet 2 ("WS2")** has fewer rows and 17 columns.

**WS2|Column A** contains a subset of data found in **WS1|Column H**.

These two columns have the same labels in the Header row.

I want WS1 to only display rows whose Column H values are found somewhere in **W2|Column A**.

I can do this manually, of course:

1. Set filters on the header row of WS1
2. Expand the filter for WS1|Column H
3. Deselect all
4. Click the box beside each value that is found in WS2|Column A

But that is too cumbersome. I've tried to figure out  way to do this with AutoFilters but that doesn't seem possible.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Note that the values in **WS2|Column A** may change over time. It would be awesome if anytime I do this it will be based upon the current values in WS2.

Comment: Two things:
(1) I want to be clear that I need to display all of columns for the filtered rows in WS1, not just the matching cells;

(2) Ideal would be to display the matches within WS1. However, if for some reason it's easier, displaying the filtered data in a new worksheet would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this small macro:

```
Sub AutoFilterHelper()
    Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, N As Long
    Dim ary()
    Set sh1 = Sheets("WS1")
    Set sh2 = Sheets("WS2")

    N = sh2.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    ReDim ary(1 To N - 1)

    For i = 1 To N - 1
        ary(i) = sh2.Cells(i + 1, "A").Value
    Next i

    sh1.Range("H:H").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=(ary), Operator:=xlFilterValues
End Sub
```

It will grab the data from **WS2** and use it for the filter criteria in **WS1.**

If **WS2** changes, just re-run the macro.

Macros are very easy to install and use:

1. ALT-F11  brings up the VBE window
2. ALT-I
   ALT-M opens a fresh module
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE window as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To use the macro from Excel:

1. ALT-F8
2. Select the macro
3. Touch RUN

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thank you, Gary's Student. I will give that a try, but because of issues with my workflow I'd like to be able to do this without a macro if possible. Is it not possible to do this with filters in some way?

Comment: @JBB   This DOES use filters.........the macro just automates what you would have to do manually.

Comment: Gotcha. I'll give it a try and let you know. Much appreciated!

Comment: I finally got a chance to try this. It didn't work, but that's probably me. I copied your macro above into a new macro. I edited it by using the real titles of my worksheets and ran it. I got an error. It is quite likely that I didn't put the real worksheet names in correctly.

Here's an example: I replaced:

Set sh1 = Sheets("WS1")
   with
Set sh1 = Sheets("[JB''s Status Report (Internal) 2c141a90.xlsx]Page1_1")

Did I do this incorrectly? Note that the two worksheets will always been in different workbooks. I didn't mention that in my question.

Comment: I hope I haven't overstayed my welcome on this question. Details that I now realize I should have included are:
(1) The two worksheets will be part of different workbooks, and
(2) The workbook and worksheet file names will be variable
I can modify the macro with correct names each time or, if this magic can happen, the macro could prompt me for the name